# Invalid Syntax Python

Tags: syntax

```
def solution(t, p):
    extracted_number = []
    answer = 0 
    while(len(t) >= len(p)):
        extracted_number.append(t[:len(p)])
        t = t[1:]

    for x in extracted_number:
        if(int(x) <= int(p)):
            answer +=1    
    return answer
```

I want to make the code concise, so I did this.

answer +=1 for x in extracted_number if (int(x) < int(p)) --> invalid syntax

How to revise?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try out `answer=answer+1` and then u can return that answer variable